# how to use pug-bootstrap module in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I installed the  [pug-bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug-bootstrap) module in a nodejs  project. I am trying to create a menu from a navbar.

I have done those files:

layout.pug:

```
include /node_modules/pug-bootstrap/_bootstrap.pug
```

index.pug:

```
extends layout

block head
  +navbar("menu")
  +nav_item("#", undefined, true)
    string test

block body
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
```

the _bootstrap.pug contains the bootstrap css file : https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css. But it is not loaded on the webpage.

Someone know why? And how to fix that?

Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you extend a part of a template with `block`, you're replacing any code that was already in that block, before. In this case, I assume that the `head` included a reference to that CSS file, which you're overwriting.

Generally speaking, use `append` instead of `block` for the `head` section (see [this page](https://pugjs.org/language/inheritance.html) from their docs). That way, previous content of parent templates is not overwritten.

In your usecase, I am doubtful whether you should be placing anything at all in that `head` block, since it is reserved for meta-tags, not for actual visible content. In other words: You'll need to move the code you have there to the `body` anyway, since visible document objects belong in the `body`, not in the `head`.